# Why are flexbox child items not stretching to fill parent container (incl. jsfiddle)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

According to the documentation on CSS-tricks, using `justify-content: stretch`, a flexbox child item should stretch within its container to fill the available space.
I have a flexbox container where I set the main axis to be column direction, then in this container I place two div flexbox items. I want them to fill the available vertical space equally (so I believe `flex: 0 1 auto` should do it).

Here is the JS fiddle:

```css
body {
  height: 100%
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.in {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="in">Inside</div>
  <div class="in">
  Inside
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but you specified a fixed height .. and it's `flex:1 1 auto`

Comment: So change height of .in to percent? I‘ll try

Comment: no need to specify height since you want it to fill the space, simply consider the `flex` property

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Temani Afif:

```css
body {
  height: 100%
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.in {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="in">Inside</div>
  <div class="in">
  Inside
  </div>
</div>
```